# Kusto query max x by y

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying write a simple Kusto query to find the max value of x for each y. To be more specific, I'm querying the Azure Data Explorer sample table "Covid", trying to get the max number of deaths by country. I tried using a few things like this

```
Covid19
| summarize MostDeaths = max(Deaths) by Country
| project Country, MostDeaths
```

But this is not working of course. I also haven't found anything like this (simple as it is) in the documentation with its examples.

Edit: Expected results:
[image: Expected results]

Actual results: "A recognition error occurred.
Token: |
Line: 3, Position: 0"

Comment: it may help if you clarified what's not working - what does the query you included return, and how that differs from your expectation

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query, as you've written it in your question - is valid (syntactically and semantically).

You can click this deep-link to run it and see for yourself: https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3POL8tMMbTkqlEoLs3NTSzKrEpV8M0vLnFJTSzJKFawVchNrNCAcDQVkioVnPNL80qKKoHqC4rys1KTS2AiOkjaACLGJoNVAAAA

Given the error message you're seeing, I can guess that you're actually running a *different* query.

(perhaps:

- do you have a duplicate pipe (`|`) ?
- or - are you missing a linebreak between multiple queries in the same query editor tab?

)

Comment: Thanks @Yoni, I have no idea why this was not working. I literally pasted in my code here that threw the error, then pasted back in from here and it worked. Then I added `| order by MostDeaths` to get the largest death counts first.

Comment: you can also run `.show queries` against that cluster to try and find the query that failed. if you suspect this is an issue with the web explorer, please submit it as feedback using the appropriate button in the top right corner of the page (and include the client request ID as shown in the output of `.show queries`)